# Fetch response not correct

Tags: javascript, python, flask, fetch-api

I am creating a flask web app. My javascript code is supposed to send data and fetch a response from my Flask server and adjust the innerHTML of the current page with the response data. Currently upon response from the web server the entire page gets replaced with the following:
{'curr_size': '1', 'max_size': '5', 'recurring': 'on'}
So it is missing the field 'dateStr' I have tried setting it as a 'global variable' but it is still not appearing, how can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
<!--flatpickr date picker-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
<script>
  let globalVariable = null


  config = {
    enableTime: true,
    dateFormat: "H:i d-m-Y",
    altInput: true,
    altFormat: "F j, Y h:i K",
    minDate: "2024-01",
    onValueUpdate: function (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
      globalVariable = dateStr
      document.getElementById('current_availability').innerHTML = `<h3> Select class information:</h3>
        <div id='new_container'>
            <form>
                    <input type='text' id='curr_size'>Current class size</input>
                    <input type='text' id='max_size'>Maximum class size</input>
                    <input type='checkbox' id='recurring'>Recurring</input>
                    <button id='new-form-button' onclick="takeValues(${dateStr})"">
            </form>
        </div>`;

  document.getElementById("new-form-button").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
  });
 }
}
flatpickr("input[type=datetime-local]", config);

function takeValues(globalVariable) {
    var send_data = {
      curr_size: document.getElementById('curr_size').value,
      max_size: document.getElementById('max_size').value,
      recurring: document.getElementById('recurring').value,
      dateStr: globalVariable,
    }
const url = "{{ url_for('views.fetch_schedule') }}"
fetch(url, {
  cache: "no-cache",
  method: "POST",
  headers: new Headers({
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }),
  credentials: "include",
  body: JSON.stringify(send_data),
})


  .then((resp) => {
    // console.log(resp);
    //error checking
    //200-299
    if (!resp.ok) throw new Error('was not a valid response');
    return resp.text(); //method to extract JSON string and convert it to an Object
  })
  .then((dataobj) => {
    document.getElementById('current_availability').innerHTML = `<h3>${dataobj}</h3>`;

  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.warn(err.message);
  });
}

</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: you don't show how `takeValues` is being called - so, if the argument (globalVariable) is `undefined`, then `send_data` will NOT be included in the JSON you send - please note, the `(globalVariable)` function argument "masks" the global `let globalVariable` - so the assignment in `onValueUpdate` function will be irrelevant to the value of `globalVariable` inside `function takeValues`

Comment: Hi, takeValues is actived onClick from the innrHTML added under the flatpickr config

Comment: you still haven't shown how `takeValues` is called ... a vague description of some onClick handler does not convey what arguments are being passed when calling the function

Comment: Hi, it is there in the code.                     <button id='new-form-button' onclick="takeValues(${dateStr})"">

Comment: `onclick="takeValues(${dateStr})""` I'm surprised onclick even works with that invalid syntax - also `dateStr` is not defined anywhere, what do you think it is?

Comment: I have been trying to run as onclick="takeValues()", I am not sure of how to pass the globalVariable to the takeValues function properly in this case

Comment: isn't that what the global `globalVariable` is for? try `onclick="takeValues()"` and remove the `globalVariable` argument from `function takeValues` - therefore, using the *global* `globalVariable` which has a value assigned to it in the line `globalVariable = dateStr;`

Comment: Hi Jaro, this was my original problem, the last variable dataStr doesnt appear in the array when takeValues() is called by itself

Comment: Hi Jaro that actually worked, I unset the 'globalVariable' when defining takeValues() I understand now how this was interpreted wrong. Thankyou!

Comment: `unset the 'globalVariable' when defining takeValues()` what does that even mean? did you remove the `globalVariable` paramater from the function definition?

Answer (score -1):

You're getting the whole response object back. You just want the body `dataob.body`. Also, you should, since you're putting it in html, you should use DOMParser or similar to parse it to html.

```
.then((dataobj) => {
 let parser = DOMParser
const htmlObj = parser.parseFromString('html', text/html)
document.getElementById('current_availability').innerHTML = `<h3>${htmlObj}</h3>`;
```

})